# Invert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of lists of objects with a particular key/value pair

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, collections, nsdictionary

Here is the file I'm parsing: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pahnev/AirportJSON/master/CountriesAndAirports.json

```
{
   "Airport": [
      {
         "AirportID": "1",
         "Name": "Goroka",
         "City": "Goroka",
         "Country": "Papua New Guinea",
         "IATA-FAA": "GKA",
         "ICAO": "AYGA",
         "Latitude": "-6081689",
         "Longitude": "145391881",
         "Altitude": "5282",
         "Timezone": "10",
         "DST": "U",
         "tzdbtimezone": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
      },
      {
         "AirportID": "2",
         "Name": "Madang",
         "City": "Madang",
         "Country": "Papua New Guinea",
         "IATA-FAA": "MAG",
         "ICAO": "AYMD",
         "Latitude": "-5207083",
         "Longitude": "1457887",
         "Altitude": "20",
         "Timezone": "10",
         "DST": "U",
         "tzdbtimezone": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
      },
 ....
```

I'm trying to create a list of the countries based on it, and then from that list, the airports in that country.

I know how to do all this and have done it with dummy data.

**The problem** is the JSON file as it has list of airports, which have the country name inside them. So when I try to parse this I get multiple values of one country.

```
_countryList = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Airport.Country"];
```

With this code I get list looking something like this:

```
Papua New Guinea
Papua New Guinea
Papua New Guinea
etc...
```

So can I somehow parse this and combine all same names of one country? Or do I have to heavily modify this database?

After getting a list of countries without duplicates I would like to be able to select a country from that and get the airports that are in that country.
So Papua New Guinea would show 6 airports, Greenland 4, and so on.

Comment: Why the negative votes? Please tell me so I can edit the question.

Comment: Well, you're getting a list.  How else would you deal with airports in the same country?  You're welcome to build new data structures to make the data more readily accessible, of course.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then observe that NSLog dumps NSArrays and NSDictionarys so that the *almost* look like the source JSON, so you can NSLog your data to figure out what you have at any step along the way.

Comment: Understand that we get at least 10 "interpret my JSON for me" requests daily.  This in spite of the fact that JSON is incredibly simple and easy to understand.  People need to do their own homework.

Comment: How would json.org help me here? I know how it works. The problem is that I didn't make this database and would like to avoid creating one as it would have almost 10.000 airports in it. If there is such a list please give a link to it.

Comment: If you know how it works then you know about as much as we do.  There are things you can do with key/value coding and the like to do database-like queries, but that doesn't provide any additional function over what you presumably know how to do yourself, just makes the code a teeny bit faster and more compact.

Comment: Doing pretty similar task now. I used RestKit with CoreData and forgot about JSON parsing. It does this automatically.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON parsing anyways. You're trying to invert your mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your data through an NSSet to remove the duplicates -

```
NSArray *uniqueCountries=[[NSSet setWithArray:_countryList] allObjects];
```

Given a country you can then get the airports using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` -

```
NSString *taregtCountry=@"Papua New Guinea";
NSPredicate *countryPredicate=[NSPredicate withFormat:@"Airport.Country==%@",targetCountry];
NSArray *airportsInCountry=[json filteredArrayUsingPredicate:countryPredicate];
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second half of the question.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must be something simple. I'm just getting a crash on last line, `NSArray *airportsInCountry=[uniqueCountries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:countryPredicate];` with error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Airport."

Comment: You need to search the JSON array as per my answer, not the uniqueCountries array.

Comment: Oh my bad. Sending whole json array gives me "__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate" - error though, which is weird because json is: `NSArray *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];`
.

Comment: After some trying json wasn't array after all, so had to convert that first and everything works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to build a dictionary of arrays.

If [json valueForKeyPath:@"Airport.Country"] returns to you "Papua New Guinea", you can ask the dictionary to return to you the object for the key "Papua New Guinea".  If you get back something (Array of airports), simply add the airport to that array.  Otherwise you allocate a new array with that airport and set it to the dictionary under the country key.

The keys for the dictionary are the countries and the value for each key would be the array of airports.  Since a dictionary does not hold duplicate keys, your data structure would match what you are trying to accomplish.